# How to decrease the Volley-JSON Response load time from a JSON URL while fetching huge data in Android?

Tags: android, json, python-3.x, android-studio, android-volley

I am developing an android application which fetches data from a hosted Django REST API url and displays it using RecyclerView Adapter library of android. Now the problem is that since the data is huge(around 15000 approx. rows in json) the Volley library first tries and loads the whole of data (which causes a lot of delay even on a fast network connection) since the Response object of the JSONArray class retrieves the whole json data at once before setting of the RecyclerView Adapter even starts. How do i reduce this delay or how do i start setting up the recycler adapter dynamically?

Comment: you can use android's paging library and make your api support pagination.. this will help you load data faster and only that which you want to show first...

use this link for example https://medium.com/@husayn.hakeem/android-by-example-googles-recent-android-paging-library-pokedex-d9ec1d4986e9

Answer (score 0):

As stated here: Many apps consume data from a data source that contains a large number of items, but only display a small portion at a time. The Paging Library helps your app observe and display a reasonable subset of this data
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/